# WordPress site 500 error - RewriteCond: bad flag delimiters

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I see lots of other threads with this same issue, but nothing seems to be working for me, and my .htaccess file isn't as complicated as what it looks like these others are.

Everything was fine until a day or so ago when the site won't load anymore.  Gives me a 500 Internal Server Error.

Looking at the logs on the server I see the following happening:

[Mon Oct 20 04:08:21.546473 2014] [core:alert] [pid 4758:tid 139696409585408] [client 72.135.98.207:56622] /home/account/public_html/dynamictabletennis.com/.htaccess: RewriteCond: bad flag delimiters

The .htaccess file is nothing more than the original, basic version that I use on all my WP sites.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

I've tried deleting the file on the server and uploading a fresh version of it, but that's not solving the problem.  I've searched through other threads with this issue, but they all seem to have extra stuff in their htaccess file from other plugins and what-not that I'm not using and doesn't reflect what I'm seeing.

Any information on how to troubleshoot this and get it resolved would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: FWIW, there's absolutely nothing wrong with your .htaccess file. Maybe a mod_rewrite issue?

Comment: Check the line-endings that were used in that .htaccess

Comment: Well, I swear I did this like 20 times already, but I just now deleted the .htaccess of the server again and re-uploaded a fresh one and now it kicked in again.  No idea what the heck was going on here.  I'm comparing the 2 and I just don't see any difference.  Very strange.

Comment: @stealthyninja, maybe extra white space or something..??

Comment: Could have been white space or an extra CR or LF in there. Sometimes even an editor including BOM.